# Event on an Image in iOS

Tags: objective-c

I am pretty new to iOS development, so this may seem to be a stupid question.. In my xib file, i have taken a UIImageView  that will show an image when the page is loaded. But when a user taps on an image, I want the next view to be loaded.. But I am not able to do that because we cannot have a delegate not a target-action mechanism for a UIImage view.. Many places, I found a workaround.. using a button and then placing an image on it, and then using it.. but I want the first way to work.. Please help..

Comment: Add a tap gesture recognizer to the image view (and be sure to set userInteractionEnabled to yes for the image view, it's no by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  UITapGestureRecognizer ,and Don't forget to set `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` because by default image not having UserInteraction.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];


-(void)handleSingleTap:(id)sender {
// push you view here
}
```

(OR) If you want

> take button with BackGround image.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

button.frame = CGRectMake(270,10,30,30);

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using UIImageView, you can use UIButton.

```
  UIButton *myBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [myBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image_Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage @"your_image_Name"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [myBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

also write button action:

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
// Do whatever you want
}
```

In Case of XIB, Just use UIButton instead of UIImageView and set Background Image for both state Normal & Highlighted as you want. Rest you can manage button's action from XIB.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a fully transparent `UIButton` on top of your `UIImageView`... It should be preferred as each element has a clean semantics.